# Python not returning after "webbrowser.get"

Tags: python

Running python 3.9.7 with webbrowser,

When opening web page, page opens but program hangs...web page opens but "asdf" never gets printed to console.

my code:

```
import webbrowser

#open chrome
print("opening browser")
url = 'https://www.google.ca/'
webbrowser.get('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s').open(url)

print("asdf")
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Works fine for me. I'm using a Python 3.9 environment in PyCharm.

Comment: same here. works fine

Comment: Dang !! Wonder why it hangs on my machine.   I am running windows 10 Enterprise, Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2176M  CPU @ 2.70GHz   2.71 GHz with 16 GB ram   :(

Comment: One other thing, when I manually close Chrome, the script finishes...ie:"asdf" gets printed on console   ..

Comment: Since you are specifying an explicit command line to launch the browser, you need to end it with a `&` to launch the browser in the background.

Answer (score 0):

With the following change it works!

```
import webbrowser
print("opening browser")
url = 'https://www.google.ca/'
webbrowser.open(url)
print("asdf")
```